# Where does venv get pip from?

Tags: python, linux, pip, python-venv, manjaro

On a linux(Manjaro) system I had a couple of copies of `pip`. Some were at the system level and some at the user level and some withing virtual environments where they had been updated to levels higher than the system or user.

I did not like this b/c depending on what I was doing I would have to know what pip is was using, so I wanted to remove them and install pip at the user level and update it to the latest. I have removed every copy of pip that I can find. Finding them I used an exhaustive search on the command line using `find` command.

If I try to use pip in any terminal now I get that it is not a found command. BUT if I do `python -m venv ./venv` I find that a copy of pip has made its way into the venv folder.

**Where is this copy of pip coming from?**

I have check inside ~/.local/, /etc/, /root/, ... like I said, i have done an exhaustive search to see if it is just residing on my system.

**EDIT:**

I decided to look into the `venv` module because that was the built-in virtual environment that I have been using.

In `/usr/lib/python3.9/venv/` there are `__main__.py` and `__init__.py`. Without delving into python usage/implentation specifics **I am assuming** that the `__main__.py` file is importing the `main()` function by use of `from . import main` in the `__main__.py` file. Then, in `__init__.py` the main function calls the `create()` function as part of the `EnvBuilder` class defined inside. That `create()` function eventually leads to `_setup_pip()` where there is this

```
    cmd = [context.env_exe, '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade',
                                                '--default-pip']
    subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

So if pip is not found locally they are going out on the network to get it.

So if this is true then that leads me to want to look at passing a flag to venv when creating the virtual environment so that I can see what it is doing. As of now using `python -m venv ./venv` just leads to it pausing for a moment while it does the operation then it comes back to the command line prompt. With some sort of output I may have been able to see the download of pip and moved forward quicker.

Comment: may use `which pip` or `pip --version` that may show you the location of pip. usually at /usr/local/bin/pip

Comment: @Asdfg, "If I try to use pip in any terminal now I get that it is not a found command. " The command is not found at the command line. When running which you get `which: no pip in (/home/nedwards/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin)`

Comment: do you find it at /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip?

Comment: @Asdfg No pip there.